# Trying to use SEARCH function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, search, microsoft-excel-2011, countif

I'm trying to do something on Excel which is a little bit over my head and was wondering if anyone out there can help:

I'm trying to search through a table (specifically one column) for several variables at once and tally them individually and in total.

An additional issue is that each cell in the column contains multiple words separated by commas. for example:

```
android,bug_report,cv_106213,delete_account,server_api
```

So I need to be able to find "bug_report" but also "apples".

I'd like to return a tally that looks something like this:

```
apples:      5
bug_report:  4
Total:       9
```

I'm using Excel 2011 for Mac

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a realistic example. Your tally cannot be derived from the example you posted.  Also indicate if an item can appear more than once in a cell, and need to be counted more than once. Depending on your real problem, it should be solvable using wild-cards.  Although, if there are "overlapping" strings, other approaches may be better.

Answer (score 1):

As @callumDS33 stated, you can use `COUNTIF` for a single criteria. Using this would give you a count of all `apple` and another instance would give you a count of ALL `bug_report` results (*including those not related to* `apple`). You can then sum those to get the results of the example you gave.

**If you want to count the number of `apple` occurrences which also have `bug_report`**, you need something different. To count multiple criteria, use `COUNTIFS`.

> COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2]…)

Let's say your data is in column A. You can enter the following formula in `C1` to count the number of times `apple` and `bug_report` appear together.

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, "*apples*", A:A, "*bug_report*")
```

Comment: Can I search for any of a set of values as one of my criteria?Example: criteria1 is a single value, criteria2 is an array    
 ={countifs(A:A, $F$1:$F$5, B:B, "*bug_report*")} where F1:F5 is {bannan, apple, raspberry, peanut, grape}

Comment: Yes, but the result is an array the same size as `F1:F5` so you need another function to sum the array and give your total I use `SUMPRODUCT` to avoid "array entry" so you get this formula `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,$F$1:$F$5,B:B,"bug_report"))`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the text to columns (delimited > comma > finish). If your string is in cell **A1** then this function will split it by commas into cells **A1:E1**. Then use the following formula to count the occurences of apples:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$E$1,"apples")
```

Comment: Or you could use `=COUNTIF($A$1:$E$1,"*apples*")` without the text-to-columns, although this doesn't account for multiple instances of the same word in one cell.

Comment: without text-to-columns I think it should be `=COUNTIF($A$1,"*apples*")` but since it doesn't account for multiple, I didn't go for that option.